# custom syntax highlight for minted

Tags: minted, pygments

I am trying to get a custom syntx highlight for minted. My actual code for this style looks like this:

```
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Keyword, Name, Comment, String, Error, \
    Number, Operator, Generic

class MyStyle(Style):
default_style = ""
styles = {
    Comment:                '#8F8F8F',
    Keyword:                '#0773BA',
    Name:                   '#AB2CA2',
    Name.Function:          '#F0C648',
    Name.Class:             'bold #0f0',
    String:                 '#36991D'
}
```

I got the template for this new style from the pygments documentation (http://pygments.org/docs/styles/), but I don't know how can I make pygment to use my style. The document says, that I need to drop it into a styles folder of my pygment package. But I can't find this folder? I am on a Ubuntu system.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On Ubuntu 14.04, `dpkg -L python-pygments` shows that the package provides the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/styles`. This could be what you are looking for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about Python & Pygments than about TeX.

Comment: @Jubobs, I disagree, while this does involve Python and Pygments, the question does not request help on either. It requests help on how to include it in a TeX document. I actually came to this page via Google, looking for answer to this very question. But because it was closed, am I not able to do so.

Comment: @TylerCrompton Read the end of the question again. It specifically asks help about Pygments, which makes it off-topic on this site. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @Jubobs Likewise, with all due respect, read the top of the question again, it is clear that the OP is asking how to use the custom style with the minted package. Minted makes it very easy to use a builtin style, but it's not clear how to use a custom style. This question would get closed on SO because it would be more fitting for this site.

Comment: Here's the answer, setup.py entry_points, see https://github.com/jschaf/pygments-style-goggles/blob/master/setup.py#L45, then you can use `style=goggles` in minted.  The info on this was scattered, but mostly at http://pygments.org/docs/plugins/ and http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools